# "Custom Search JSON API' cost USD 5 per query. What is considered a query?

Tags: google-contacts-api

"Custom Search JSON API' cost USD 5 per query.
What is considered a query?
Assuming I searched an expression and get 3 pages, each page 10 items. Total 30.
How many queries here, 1, 3 or 30?
Is there a way to get more than 10 items per page?

Answer (score 0):

No thats wrong, it costs 5$ per 1000 querys and 100 querys a day is free:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#pricing

Every api request will be one query - you talk about response items. That's someting different and has no impact to the query counter.

10 items per page is maximum. (num Parameter):
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list#query-parameters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).